# Creating month to month visualization in Power BI when associated dates not provided

Tags: powerbi, bar-chart, visualization, powerquery

Below is a small representative sample of data that I have loaded into Power BI to display a visualization.  The "Monthly Savings" data changes with time. And whatever those numbers are at the end of each month, I will like to display their total using some sort of bar chart - so that we will have a bar chart that shows that totals value for January, February, March, etc. of the year 2023 (and same thing for subsequent years moving forward)

But the below data will not come with any date/time information. I just need to know that at each month end, I need to report what those month end totals are. And with time the totals will reflect in the bar chart showing Monthly Savings by Month

Question: How do I associate the month-end data to month-end dates in Power BI, if the source data does not come with any date/time information?

[image]

Comment: Label your month-end data pulls. How would you do it if it were paper, and not pbi? You'd label the folder, right?

Comment: You will need to take monthly snapshots of the data and store them in a separate table. There are different ways to achieve this, i.e. in the source database, or with scripts and online storage.

Comment: I like both of your ideas. I'll try one or the other and see what happens